# QPointer to QHash

Tags: qt, pointers, qhash, qpointer

Is it possible to use QPointer with QHash?

```
QPointer<QHash<QString, QPointer<QStringList>> >  pHash;
```

Comment: I should say that the code do compile, but I get strange errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QPointer can only be used with QObject subclasses. Thus it cannot be used with QHash or QStringList, as both aren't QObject's. If the code above compiles for you, that's probably because you don't use pHash yet? Even initializing such a QPointer, e.g.

```
QPointer<QHash<QString, QString> > foo( new QHash<QString, QString>() );
```

gives errors like the following one (gcc):

```
error: cannot convert ‘QHash<QString, QString>*’ to ‘QObject*’ in initialization
```

If you really need (smart) pointers to containers, try [QSharedPointer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html), which doesn't require the contained object to be of any specific type.
Usually one creates containers on the stack though, creating them on the heap is unidiomatic and unnecessary in almost all cases. Qt's containers are [implicitly shared](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html), thus copying them is cheap.

Comment: +1 for spotting that `QPointer` can only be used with `QObject`. +1 for `QSharedPointer` alternative. And +1 for spotting that containers are implicitely shared :).

Comment: Yes, it's when I try to use pHash I get the errors. Thanks a lot for your nice answer and the alternative.